# Appointment Setting Addon

Tags: add-on, recommendation-request

Does anyone know of a good online appointment solution? It would be for a salon so they would need to be able to book an appointment in 15-30min intervals.  I looked at rEEservation but it looks like that one only handles full days. Any help will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution that has over 12 months of solid development, and is built entirely within EE. It's currently being used for a similar purpose to schedule appointments at specific intervals for healthcare providers. It's currently being used by around 10,000 users total and has been well tested.

That said, it's not a conventional add-on one can install and will never be in this current iteration. I do however have a reasonable rate I will install it, and even customize it directly for your needs. I have demoed this system for quite a few people in EE, and would be glad to give you a demo.

This isn't a traditional answer of "a how to" for StackExchange, so sorry for the informality, but I believe this is the absolute best scheduling app available for EE. It's very robust and 100% customizable and works with virtually any other add-on.

If you are interested, contact support[at]objectivehtml.com

Comment: Could your solution be used as a booking system for a holiday properties site where there are many different properties?

Comment: @foamcow Absolutely. I have already been talking to various people about doing this. Currently it's only in the context of dr/patient schedule, but it's built like CartThrob in the sense that it's a framework built specifically for scheduling. It's all on the front-end using template tags and a JS library. Each timeslot is stored as an entry, and there is a UI to create 100's of entries in a just a couple clicks. Happy to give a demo if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a booking system for holiday properties using SolSpace Calendar. Although my solution only books full days there is no reason it could not be done in time slots since Calendar supports this.

With that said, it was horrible to do but that is partly down to the other requirements of the site - hundreds of bookable resources and property owners able to create bookings from an SAEF. If you are dealing with a few bookable resources and this bookings are managed in the CP then it would be pretty standard usage of the add-on.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling in EE isn't easy to setup. Your best bet is to look into Justin's addon or to look at a 3rd party tool which would sit inside an EE template but be served by the 3rd party service via JS or a script you install on the same server which lives beside EE on the server.

There are tons of options for Salon scheduling which do the job well... For example [**Simple Salon**](http://www.simplesalon.com) has a small monthly fee, no contract, SMS reminders and online bookings.

A Google search for "online scheduling for salons" will get you a ton of options.

Comment: As for external booking services I'd also throw in Booking Bug. I haven't used it but it was a strong contender based on research I did for an old project.